# Box2D and Tiled Map

Tags: box2d

Question about render tiled map and Box2D.
Example of tiled map drawing pseudo code is:

```
draw tile layers loop
{
    draw tiles loop
    {
        draw_tile();
    }
}
```

Where should I call box2d `step()` function?
If I call it **outside** "draw tile layers loop", then there is delay in Box2D simulation and it runs very slowly, same happens **inside** "draw layers loop". If I call it inside "draw tiles loop" it runs very fast. What is the correct way of using Box2D? Box2D documentation is not quite understandable to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Box2D step function is best called once per frame. So you would want to call it outside of your loops. Calling it multiple times per frame speeds up the world simulation if using a fixed step size. (alternatively, you could call it using the delta time to make the physics more frame rate independent)

If you are getting slow physics when run once per frame the problem is not caused by the placement of the physics step.